# How to get an event on text attr change using inspector jointjs

Tags: typescript, jointjs, rappid

In the callback handler for text change from inspector, I want to perform some logic upon the entered text in inspector text field before it gets applied to the selected cell on paper. For this I have to prevent the default action.

I have successfully implemented it using a Backbone event with rappid 2.0.0. This is the earlier implementation -

```
'change [data-attribute="attrs/text/text"]': function(evt) {

    evt.preventDefault();
    var editedText = $(evt.target).text();
    var convertedText = my.workflow.getApiName(editedText);
    var selectedElement = this.selection.collection.toArray()[0];
    var selectedElementId = selectedElement.id;
    var selectedCell = this.graph.getCell(selectedElementId);
    selectedCell.attributes.apiName = editedText;
    selectedCell.attr("text/text", convertedText);
}
```

But now I have updated the implementation to angular 6 component using typescript,

```
const graph = this.graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
graph.on('change [data-attribute="attrs/text/text"]', (cell: joint.dia.Cell, evt: any) => {
 evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Here evt.preventDefault() is giving error.

Tried searching for a solution to this, but didn't get through.

Answer (score 3):

There no `evt` argument there.

see more here https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.1/joint.html#dia.Graph.events

In the inspector, however, might be some useful options for you:

`validateInput`, `getFieldValue` (https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/rappid/v2.3/ui.html#ui.Inspector) :

createInspector: function(cell) {

```
var inspector = joint.ui.Inspector.create('.inspector-container', _.extend({
    cell: cell,
    /**
     * @param {HTMLElement} element
     * @param {string} path - field path e.g `attrs/label/text`
     * @param {string} type - text, content-editable, range ...
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    validateInput: function(element, path, type) {
        // ... validations
        console.log('validate', arguments);
        return true; // `false` - prevent propagate changes to the cell
    },
    /**
     * @param {HTMLElement} element
     * @param {string} type - text, content-editable, range ...
     */
    getFieldValue: function(element, type) {
        console.log('getFieldValue', arguments);
    }
}, App.config.inspector[cell.get('type')]));

return inspector;
```

},

you can also log all events:

```
// also possible as `graph.on('all'...`, `paper.on('all' ... `
inspector.on('all', function() {
    console.log('Inspector event - ', arguments);
})
```